# Items from assets directory not showing in either ionic serve or ionic cordova run

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

Images and svgs from assets directory are not showing in the `ionic serve`. Seems the assets folder is not copying in the www directory during build.

My project directory structure is:
-src
--app
--assets
---icon
---svg
--environments
--theme

I have already tried adjusting the src location of the images and svgs. But it seems none of them worked!

Path that I already tried:
assests/
/assests/
./assests/
../assests/
../../assests/

Error in the console says: 
GET http://localhost:8100/icon/cash-round.png 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:8100/svg/md-apps.svg 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:8100/svg/md-send.svg 404 (Not Found)

Here is the code of the html file:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>
            <img src="icon/cash-round.png"> Welcome
        </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-card class="welcome-card">
        <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-subtitle>Get Started</ion-card-subtitle>
            <ion-card-title>Welcome to Ionic</ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>
            <p>Now that your app has been created, you'll want to start building out features and components. Check out some of the resources below for next steps.</p>
            <button id="demo">Click me</button>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

Let me know if I have to install any package to show image or changes in the other files like package.json or angular.json

Answer (score 0):

this is how to refer to the assets folder

```
<ion-img src="/assets/shapes.svg"></ion-img>
```

ionic serve uses src not www i believe

cmd - `ionic start example sidemenu` has an example in the home screen

Comment: But actually it is not copying the files from assets folder to www folder after I build the project.

Comment: ```ionic start example sidemenu``` Also not showing the images and svgs